# Is engineering basically controlling oscillators?

Tags: mathematics

When an engineer optimizes a hoe to make an excavator, what do they actually do? I guess that when they see a room for improvement of the hoe, they start solving differential equations. But as the solutions can be transformed under Fourier transform/series, so it's just controlling oscillators. So even if the problem doesn't involve waves or vibrations, what they actually do is adding new oscillators and making old oscillators more or less resonated.

Is this correct that everything they do involves differential equations? To quote Sidney Coleman:

> The career of a young theoretical physicist consists of treating the harmonic oscillator in ever-increasing levels of abstraction.

The Wikipedia page [Mathematical optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) doesn't talk about this. I wonder how this is viewed in the engineering perspective.

Comment: Theoretical physics and engineering are *very* different disciplines. To paraphrase a quote from Feynman (from memory!) "Physicists usually focus their attention on understanding the simplest possible situation they can imagine. They leave engineers to worry about all the complications that happen in the real world." ;)

Comment: Ooker: Material/chemical engineering - often no oscillations involved; rheology - frequencies so low you won't get half a period of oscillation over the entire lifetime of the construction. Pyrotechnics - before you reach 1/4 the wavelength the subject ceases to exist. Civil engineering - you're working with naturally occurring simple phenomena and individual local conditions so different from site to site that trying to transform it into frequency spectrum and simplifying that way will get you lynched by locals.

Comment: Engineering is where physics, law, economics, psychology and artistic domains meet. You can not, usually, solve legal issues with differential equations. Although if the excavator killed a scoolbus full of children it may be one of the things you use to demonstrate due diligence.

Answer (score 5):

No.

First, there is much much more to most engineering disciplines than analyzing the response of something.

Second, even when that is part of the task, it isn't done by "adding oscillators", whatever that even means.

Comment: I think he's talking about the process of optimizing a design and the oscillators are abstract concepts in the process, not actual physical vibration.

Comment: @user1318499 yes, see my edit. Olin, can you elaborate on what tasks engineers need to do in optimization? Actually I'm surprise that there is no [tag:optimization] tag.

Comment: Everything a professional engineer does is "optimization" in some sense of the word, but most of it is not "mathematical optimization"

Comment: @alephzero  that's an optimistic view of the engineer's task :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft can you elaborate that?